# ASP.NET suddenly rejecting large files. Missing settings?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, iis-8

It went unnnoticed bcause our test suite was down a month.

It seems ASP.NET at some point started rejecting files larger than around 20mb for one of our web applications. This is an "old" API with 4.7.2 runtime now.

Rejects are just rejected.

The runtime is configured as:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" maxRequestLength="102400" enableVersionHeader="false" />
```

which indicaets 102400kb max size, i.e. 100mb. Server is 2016, running dotnet 4.7.2 and having core runtimes for other sites installed.

Requests get rejected in Chrome with "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'" which indicates some sort of crash/timeout - we DO send CORS ehaders back immediately before and it works nicely for files up to around 20mb in size. It should accept files up to around 100mb (as per settins). The client side limit is 50mb. Definitely not the 25mb that are our failing test case.

In repro, the request never enters the ASP.NET written upload handler - so it is rejected at an earlier level and i have no way to know why.

Anyone aware of any change done to the runtime in the meantime? This part of the codebase has been stagble for about 9 months with tests just working, so I assumea chakge on the backend somewhere.

Comment: Chrome is also continuously in development and a new update was rolled out this week, and one of the crusade projects they're working on now is tightening of security. Could it be that Chrome got more strict?

Comment: Not with the 70 update (this predates is by 2 weeks). It also happens on Firefox ;)